# How to Initialise a Handle

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi, win32gui, win32-process

Error:

```
Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'TextLabelVar' is being used without 
being initialized.
```

Illustrative Code:

```
HWND VarText;
char Disps[100];
float some_number;
WINAPI WndProc(..)
{   

    switch(...) 
    case WM_CREATE:
    TextLabelVar=CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE,TEXT("Edit"), TEXT("Val."), WS_CHILD \
                | WS_VISIBLE, 380, 50, 140, 20, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    break;

    case WM_MESSAGEFROMANOTHERWINDOW:
    some_number=1298.123123;
    sprintf(Disps,"%f",some_number);
    SetWindowText(TextLabelVar,TEXT(Disps));

}
```

Question:
Ok, I get the error TextLabelVar is being used without initialisation. I got similar error for var Disps. I then declared char Disps[100]; This showed no error. Now, the error moves onto a handle. I am not sure I can declare a handle as array and it makes sense. How do I solve this?

Comment: Are you sure it goes into the case WM_CREATE?

Comment: I think it's a simple case of whatever system that outputs "Run-Time Check Failure #3" not knowing that the variable is actually initialized, but in another code-path. In other words, it doesn't know that it's initialized in another case. You can probably solve it by simply assigning zero to `TextLabelVar` in its declaration.

Comment: @doctorlove Why? What do you mean? I want to create a text field when window is created. I have main window too. Then, I want to update text field when WM_MESSAGEFROMANOTHERWINDOW comes. Where is it supposed to be placed?

Comment: DavidHeffernan, thanks. @doctorlove is correct. It better go under WinMain.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg That's not quite it. It's a runtime error. So initialising to `0` just suppresses the error and `SetWindowText` is then called with a `0` window handle.

Comment: As an aside, `TEXT(Disps)` is wrong. That macro can only be used with literals. If you want my advice I suggest you give up trying to write code that can be compiled for ANSI or Unicode. Since Win9x is dead, choose to write Unicode aware code and drop any pretence otherwise. In fact your code already is clearly ANSI only since you use `char`. Which means that the code will break horribly if you tried to compile for Unicode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a run-time error. What it is telling you is that `TextLabelVar` is being read before it has been initialised. And that means that the `WM_MESSAGEFROMANOTHERWINDOW` case statement executed before `WM_CREATE`.

From the comments you've assigned `0` to `TextLabelVar` to suppress the warning, but then of course the call to `SetWindowText` cannot succeed since the window handle you pass is `0`.

To tackle the problem you need to understand why `WM_MESSAGEFROMANOTHERWINDOW` is being handled before `WM_CREATE`.